# TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode contains CR LF

Tags: delphi

Is this behavio(u)r intended?

```
...
uses
 System.NetEncoding;

...

var
  s: String;
begin
  s := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode('asjjdhgfaoösjkdhföaksjdfhöasjdfhasdkjasdhfköajsjhdfajssssd');
end;
```

s contains a CR LF:

YXNqamRoZ2Zhb8O2c2prZGhmw7Zha3NqZGZow7Zhc2pkZmhhc2RramFzZGhma8O2YWpzamhkZmFq **'#$D#$A'** c3Nzc2Q=

[image: Local variables]

The issue with this is that all my http calls return a bad request. The other party does not expect this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In that case you can create an instance with the proper parameters yourself:

```
var
  s: String;
  base64: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(0); // CharsPerLine = 0 means no line breaks
  try
    s := base64.Encode('asjjdhgfaoösjkdhföaksjdfhöasjdfhasdkjasdhfköajsjhdfajssssd');
  finally
    base64.Free;
  end;
end;
```